# Proxied IOS App doesn't send http/s requests? How are they fetching the data then?

Tags: ios, http, https, proxy, burp

I'm currently trying to intercept API calls of an IOS App.
Why? I want to reverse engineer their private API and use it for more specific requests.
However, the App has nearly zero `https` traffic and traffic via web sockets.
The only requests they have sent during the start of the app were on to:

- Mapbox (probably to display maps)
- and Google to request a `fcmtoken` for Cloud Messaging

Thus, I was wondering how they fetch the data displaying in the app.
[image]

Comment: Does the app behaves normal? May be it uses certificate pinning and thus does not perform network operations except the one you see. Alternatively it may be possible that the main part of the app uses a custom HTTP client that ignores your proxy settings.

Comment: The app behaves as without proxy.

Comment: May be because the transfert of data is not done using https but some other protocol and on other port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more deep research and reverse engineering the android app, I noticed that the app uses flutter. The problem with that is that Flutter uses Dart and Dart is not proxy aware and uses its own certificate store. Hence, the application doesn't take any proxy settings from the system and sends data directly to the server. Thus, I wasn't able to intercept the request using Burpsuite.

I was able to intercept the firebase and mapbox requests as they were imported as nodejs packages.